# How can QueryOver be used to filter for a specific class?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, queryover

I am currently dynamically constructing queries like so:

```
QueryOver<Base, Base> q = QueryOver.Of<Base>();

if (foo != null) q = q.Where(b => b.Foo == foo);
// ...
```

Now there are multiple mapped subclasses of `Base` (e. g. `Derived`) which I want to filter on, basically something like:

```
if (bar) q = q.Where(b => b is Derived); // does not work
```

or:

```
if (bar) q = q.Where(b => b.DiscriminatorColumn == 'derived'); // dito
```

How do I best achieve that, preferably - but not neccessarily - in a type-safe way? Can this be done using LINQ, too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *not* intuitive, but the following should work fine (QueryOver):

```
if (bar) q = q.Where(b => b.GetType() == typeof(Derived));
```

I'm not sure about a way to do this in LINQ-to-NH.

Comment: Really nice. I'd have to use the restrictions previously, because I did not know about this construct.

Answer (score 1):

The general `QueryOver`, asking for a `subtype`, would look like this:

```
Base alias = null;

var query = session.QueryOver<Base>(() => alias);

// this statement would be converted to check of the discriminator
query.Where(o => o is Derived);

var list = query.List<Derived>();
```

But this would result in a statement, expecting that discirminator is "MyNamespace.Derived". If this si not the case, we can use this approach:

```
Base alias = null;

var query = session.QueryOver<Base>(() => alias);

// here we can compare whatever value, we've used as discriminator
query.Where(Restrictions.Eq("alias.class", "Derived"));

var list = query.List<Derived>();
```

Here we are using the feature of NHibernate: ".class" which does return the value of discriminator

More details could be found here:

- [17.1.4.1. Alias and property references](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-aliasreferences)

Comment: I have had the first version, but given that my discriminator column is using an integer it did not work; good to know, though.

Comment: Yeah, the Andrew's snippet is really nice. Enjoy NHibernate