# Where clause with type check "is" operator does not use discriminator

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-criteria

I have mapped a class hierarchy in NHibernate. Simple as that:

```
class abstract Animal
class Dog : Animal
class Cat: Animal
class Cow: Animal
```

In mapping I have discriminator values set on ANIMAL_TYPE column:

```
Dog -> dog
Cat -> cat
Cow -> cow
```

All kind of queries work. Except this one, when I need to fetch objects of two particular types. I wrote is like this:

```
QueryOver.Of<Animal>().Where(animal => animal is Dog || theme is Cat)
```

And I receive no items in result. When I look into generated query, NHibernate generates:

```
(this_.ANIMAL_TYPE = @p0 or this_.ANIMAL_TYPE = @p1)
```

which is fine, but the values in **@p0** and **@p1** parameters contain full class name, eg.

```
Zoo.Model.Cat
```

instead of discriminator values. How can I solve it? Do I have to keep my discriminator values in sync with type names? I would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question & answer should be working for you: [How can QueryOver be used to filter for a specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21677196/1679310) *(asked just a day before you)*

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Animal>()
    .Where(animal => animal.GetType() == typeof (Dog) 
                  || animal.GetType() == typeof (Cat)
          );

var list = query.List<Animal>();
```