# Nhibernate query-over syntax how to filter for a given alias for a subclass type

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have few classes mapped as `subclasses` to a table using a *discriminator* column. But the *discriminator* column is not mapped to any field (even in the base class). I want to create Query (in `QueryOver` syntax) which filters by the *type* of the **subclass**

E.g. Table:

```
Orders        (Id,OrderType,Amount,Qty...)
// OrderType is the discriminator column
```

mapped classes:

```
DeliveryOrder (Id,Amount,Qty...)
WorkOrder     (Id,Qty,...)
SalesOrder    (Id,Amount,...)
```

Need a query something like

Query.Where(()=>_orderAlias is DeliveryOrder)

Answer (score 2):

I remember this really [cool answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21679506/1679310) by [Andrew Whitaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497356/andrew-whitaker) to the question:

- [How can QueryOver be used to filter for a specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21677196/1679310)

and it shows syntax like this:

```
q = q.Where(b => b.GetType() == typeof(DeliveryOrder));
```

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow, enjoy NHibernate ;)